# How can a program create another executable file?

Tags: c++

Basically I'm asking how do installers work. What is the code that creates a new executable file?

EDIT: It sounds like the answer I'm looking for is the files are stored in archives and the installer unpacks them.

Comment: Installers don't really create executables. They usually just unpack an archive of files into their respective locations, updating the platform as needed.

Comment: An executable file is just like another file. The installer may extract it and save somewhere. This question is very vague and hard to answer, please elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you are mixing up installers with compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An installer normally extracts an appended archive and puts it to the desired directory, registers some libs and so on.

Another Task of an installer is to detect if the needed dependencies are installed and install them if needed.